# SVG Gap: wont completely fill the outer container

Tags: css, svg

My svg has a slight gap on the left side and I cannot for the life of me fix it. See the below image for what I am referring to. On the left side you can see the image slightly.

[image]

I notice this problem on Chrome and Firefox. Any ideas what the issue could be?

```css
.aw-carousel .thumbnail {
 padding: 0;
 border-radius: 5px;
 height: 24rem;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: relative;

 background-size: cover; 
 background-position: center center; 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;

 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
 box-shadow:         0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}

.aw-carousel .thumbnail-inner {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.aw-carousel .thumbnail-svg {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 100%;
}

.aw-carousel .thumbnail-content {
 padding: 1rem;
 text-align: left;
 /*background-color: #fff;*/
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="aw-carousel row">
<div class="aw-carousel-cell-third col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
  <div class="thumbnail" style="background-image: url(http://www.africaneedslions.com//fsdocuments/Social/FeaturedImages/e1d76099-362a-4d0a-825b-7f4dba2ef947/pimage_e1d76099-362a-4d0a-825b-7f4dba2ef947.jpg?v=20180313080756);">
    <div class="thumbnail-inner">
      <div class="thumbnail-svg">
        <svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 214.37 379.6" preserveAspectRatio="none"><title>wave</title><path d="M214.37,379.6H0V5.33S22.87,0,42.67,0C91.37,0,96,7.6,141,27.3c12.5,5.5,28.3,10.3,43.7,10,23.2-.3,29.7-6.4,29.7-6.4Z" style="fill:#fff"/></svg>
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-content">
        <h3 class="thumbnail-title text-uppercase">Foo</h3>
        <p>Bar</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You code does not demo the issue.

Comment: Tried it, does not show any issue...

Comment: Please create a working [mcve].

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have posted a better example although its still tricky to demo the problem.

Comment: Your demo looks ok to me in Chrome and Firefox.  Perhaps if you can work out why this sample works, but yours doesn't, you will find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**But still update this classes in your code and see...**

```
.aw-carousel .thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 24rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;

    background-size: cover; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow:         0px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    overflow:hidden;
}

.aw-carousel .thumbnail-svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left:-2px;
    width: 101%;
}
```